# Java: Cannot run program, Broken Pipe

Tags: java, macos

here is my issue:

I want to run a JAR file using a specific Java JRE which I'm downloading on the user computer. Everything works perfectly, until I start the program on a MacOS computer. Here is my code:

```
if (Utils.getUserOs().contains("mac")) {
   ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
   builder.command("chmod", "777", JavaVersionHelper.getJavaPath());
   builder.start();
}
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();  
builder.command(JavaVersionHelper.getJavaPath(), "-jar", javaFile.getPath());
builder.start();
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

`Cannont run program "PATH": error=32, Broken pipe`

Could anyone help me this ?

Thanks!

Comment: And what is the value returned by `JavaVersionHelper.getJavaPath()`?